# Openscap scanner is incorrectly failing for a multiple DNS rule and I'm not sure why

Tags: openscap

I am trying to harden UBI 8 base images using the openscap tool. The scanner has a rule:
xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_network_configure_name_resolution which checks the /etc/resolv.conf file for multiple DNS Servers. The test fails but when I check the content of that file from inside the image there are 4 nameservers. The test to check this is a regex which when put into a regex tester with the output of resolv.conf returns 4 matches (expected). I have checked the file permissions and file is readable by all.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Edit (nsswitch.conf output):

```
cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# Generated by authselect on Fri Feb 23 13:25:15 2024
# Do not modify this file manually.

# If you want to make changes to nsswitch.conf please modify
# /etc/authselect/user-nsswitch.conf and run 'authselect apply-changes'.
#
# Note that your changes may not be applied as they may be
# overwritten by selected profile. Maps set in the authselect
# profile takes always precedence and overwrites the same maps
# set in the user file. Only maps that are not set by the profile
# are applied from the user file.
#
# For example, if the profile sets:
#     passwd: sss files
# and /etc/authselect/user-nsswitch.conf contains:
#     passwd: files
#     hosts: files dns
# the resulting generated nsswitch.conf will be:
#     passwd: sss files # from profile
#     hosts: files dns  # from user file

aliases:    files
automount:  files
ethers:     files
group:      files systemd
hosts:      files dns myhostname
initgroups: files
netgroup:   files
networks:   files
passwd:     files systemd
protocols:  files
publickey:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files
shadow:     files
# Included from /etc/authselect/user-nsswitch.conf

#
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Name Service Switch config file. This file should be
# sorted with the most-used services at the beginning.
#
# Valid databases are: aliases, ethers, group, gshadow, hosts,
# initgroups, netgroup, networks, passwd, protocols, publickey,
# rpc, services, and shadow.
#
# Valid service provider entries include (in alphabetical order):
#
#   compat          Use /etc files plus *_compat pseudo-db
#   db          Use the pre-processed /var/db files
#   dns         Use DNS (Domain Name Service)
#   files           Use the local files in /etc
#   hesiod          Use Hesiod (DNS) for user lookups
#   nis         Use NIS (NIS version 2), also called YP
#   nisplus         Use NIS+ (NIS version 3)
#
# See `info libc 'NSS Basics'` for more information.
#
# Commonly used alternative service providers (may need installation):
#
#   ldap            Use LDAP directory server
#   myhostname      Use systemd host names
#   mymachines      Use systemd machine names
#   mdns*, mdns*_minimal    Use Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD
#   resolve         Use systemd resolved resolver
#   sss         Use System Security Services Daemon (sssd)
#   systemd         Use systemd for dynamic user option
#   winbind         Use Samba winbind support
#   wins            Use Samba wins support
#   wrapper         Use wrapper module for testing
#
# Notes:
#
# 'sssd' performs its own 'files'-based caching, so it should generally
# come before 'files'.
#
# WARNING: Running nscd with a secondary caching service like sssd may
#      lead to unexpected behaviour, especially with how long
#      entries are cached.
#
# Installation instructions:
#
# To use 'db', install the appropriate package(s) (provide 'makedb' and
# libnss_db.so.*), and place the 'db' in front of 'files' for entries
# you want to be looked up first in the databases, like this:
#
# passwd:    db files
# shadow:    db files
# group:     db files

# In order of likelihood of use to accelerate lookup.

gshadow:    files
# Allow initgroups to default to the setting for group.
# initgroups: files
```

Comment: what is in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?

Comment: Have added the output above @AlexD

Comment: There's always the possibility that the test fails on things that both don't have a functional impact and which can be hard to spot with the naked eye, like trailing whitespaces, TAB characters, no `\r\n` after a last entry

Answer (score 1):

You mention <kbd>4</kbd> `nameserver` entries.

That might be the problem, and depending on your system, possibly 1 too many.

### [`man 5 resolv.conf`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/resolv.conf.5.html)

```
nameserver Name server IP address
          Internet  address  of  a name server that the resolver should query, either an IPv4
          address (in dot notation), or an IPv6 address in colon (and possibly dot)  notation
          as  per  RFC  2373.   Up to MAXNS (currently 3, see <resolv.h>) name servers may be
          listed, one per keyword.  If there  are  multiple  servers,  the  resolver  library
          queries  them  in  the  order  listed.  ...
```

Comment: Windows used to have a similar limitation, the rationale was the entries after the third may never be reached before the global timeout. It's 100% true though, I've seen five and even six, with no one available that ever tested it or considered what happens when it falls over, which is usually when there is a large outage.

Comment: Have tried removing one of the nameservers. I'm scanning from outside the container and it seems like when openscap creates the container to scan it recreates that file and scans it before its fully recreated. When I install openscap within the container and run the scan it passes, but its just scanning from the otuside that causes the issue.